# Contract mined but Truffle gives error

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Something weird happened, and I can't understand what to do now. While migrating the contract to the MainNet, I received this:

```
$ truffle migrate --network live
Using network 'live'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... <TX_ADDRESS>
  Migrations: <ADDRESS>
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... <TX_ADDRESS>
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Deploying ContractOne...
  ... <TX_ADDRESS>
  ContractOne: <ADDRESS>
Saving successful migration to network...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

I've masked the addresses here. On Etherscan, the contract is successfully mined, and is accessible. However, the Dapp Truffle frontend doesn't see the contract. What to do to fix this?